Is it safe to tighten canning lids after removing from the canner?
I had trouble with some canning lids sealing (mostly metal lids with separate seals from Tattler, but often with Ball lids, too), so I have been tightening the rings immediately after removing the hot jars from the canner.  I wear oven mitts or other gloves to tighten the rings.  That pushes the seal onto the jar strongly and seals well.
The usual process taught for canning is to let the jars cool and let the lid seal as a vacuum is pulled from the cooling.  Since I've thought of tightening the rings while they're hot, I've wondered why my new practice isn't commonly taught.  It seems to work very well.  I think I can't be introducing contaminants since the ring covers the seal, and the can is hot, so it has positive pressure coming out.
I've been doing this to can chicken and beef stock, processed for 25 minutes at 12 psi.

By the time your pressure canner is open, the pressure in the jars has dropped enough that they should have sealed firmly. If any haven't, that means they've been sucking in air since the pressure dropped, and are not sterile. You can replace the lids and reprocess them, but it's not safe to simply screw them down while they're kind of hot; they are no longer hot enough for that to be safe.
Canning instructions should be taken from a reliable source and followed exactly. Do not try to improve on them. Instead, concentrate on why your lids aren't sealing. That's the actual problem you have.

Could you clarify what you mean when you say that the jars should have already sealed firmly when the canner is open?  If I'm understanding you correctly, that doesn't match what I think is everyone's experience with Ball lids: that the "ping" happens many minutes or hours after the jars are removed from the canner.  How can the lids be sealed firmly if the lid is still popped up?
Also, how could they be sucking in air when the contents are boiling hot?  Is not steam pushing out of the jar rather than sucking in?

Sorry, by "firm" I should say "airtight". Even a small drop in pressure, inevitable from the inrush of room air, is enough for that. The "ping" comes when the pressure differential is enough to buckle the lid, but that's not when it seals. And no, steam is not being generated at that point, because the jars are not boiling. No heat is being added to them. You're mixing up temperature and heat.

Hmm, I have a hard time believing that steam isn't being generated immediately after the jars are removed from the canner.  I don't know whether the jar is above or below 100 °C, but it must be very close to 100°.  Even if water is below the boiling point, significant amounts of water are still changing from liquid to gas.  Does that not mean the jar is pushing out?  What am I missing here?

Actually, now that I think about it, I have had chicken stock boil after it was removed from the canner, and more often inside the canner after the canner's lid was removed.  My guess is that there was enough heat in the jar and a bump caused nucleation.  Then some of the fat from the top the stock came out of the jar and got on top of the jar's lid.  Does that not mean the jar is pushing out, not sucking in?

We're getting outside the realm of cooking here, and into physics, but you've got the wrong idea about how boiling works, and more importantly, how temperature, pressure, and volume of a gas relate to each other. Most importantly, you seem to be confusing boiling with evaporation. If you don't believe me that a jar with essentially a one-way valve sitting on the counter, one which had previously been heated sufficiently to obviate superheating, is definitely not boiling, that would be a question for [physics.se].

Actually, wait. You’re waiting for your canner to cool down naturally before opening it, right? You’re not pulling out the weight or pouring cold water on the canner?

When I first tried the Tattler lids, I heated them before bed, took the lid off in the morning, and found all seven jars completely unsealed.  I've had some Ball lids fail with the same treatment.  More recently, I've expected the Tattler lids not to seal, so I have gently lifted the weight to relieve pressure over maybe five or ten minutes so they would be hot when I tighten the rings.

Canning instructions should be taken from a reliable source and followed exactly. Do not try to improve on them. And throw out all your existing home-canned food.

See 5:44 here.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y5r7DLtCZ_c
Also, the instructions that come with the Tattler lids say "...remove jars from canner. Check metal screw bands for tightness and retighten if necessary.  Now just let the jar cool naturally to room temperature."

Here's another, see 5:50 and 9:55.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JocJV5PPdKM
This is the CEO of Harvest Guard Canning Lids tightening the lids immediately after removing from the canner.  Granted, he's demonstrating water bath canning, but I'm sure the same procedure applies to pressure canning.

And I'm glad I found some more clarity from the Tattler website:
"Once the process is completed and the jars are removed from your canner, Let the bubbling die down (approximately 3-5 minutes), as this is pressure still releasing from the jars. Place a towel over the still hot jars (for safety) and finish tightening the metal bands."
You seem to be saying their advice will product unsafe foods.
